# upload large image(>5mb) to adobe creative cloud, process and download to android app

Tags: android, image-processing, android-studio, adobecreativesdk, creative-cloud

I want to create an android app in which an image can be split into various no.of parts (according to users choice). The image can be browsed from the phone gallery and the splitted image can be saved in a chosen folder. if the image is of size greater than 5mb, android is not able to handle it. In this case I want to upload the image to creative cloud, process it (i.e. split it) and then downloaded to be saved on phone.

I have integrated the creativesdk with my app but not able to undertand how to do the rest. I am new to android. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

While you can upload and download images with the Creative Cloud via the Creative SDK, the Creative Cloud doesn't allow you to upload and execute arbitrary scripts like this.

If you need to upload an image somewhere for further processing before uploading to the user's Creative Cloud account, you would need to create your own server script to handle this.